# Not rendering the background

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, objects, customization

I've seen people rendering single objects in Cycles without rendering the background
I know about the transparent option and I've enabled it, problem is that Cycles still spends a good amount of time to render the completely transparent tiles of the background, how do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Hello :). Even when the background is transparent, Cycles still computes the samples you set (e.g. 1000). Also notice, when you increase the number of samples by 10, rendering the transparent tiles takes only 2-3 times longer (it's not at all linear).

Comment: You can use the Render Region. If rendering an animation, see this add-on: https://blendermarket.com/products/animated-render-border/